# Limit ammount of rows deleted in table without PK

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a system where, for some reason, someone created a "categories" table without PK'ing the category's ID. I just found out that now the table has a duplicate of all the rows and is causing issues with some of my queries.

My question is: Is there a way to delete duplicate rows, leaving the 'originals' in the table, without relying on indexes?

Here's the `SELECT * FROM categories`:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| categoria | descripcion |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | Int.Cons.   |
|         2 | Delegado    |
|         3 | Personal    |
|         4 | Comun       |
|         5 | Proveedor   |
|         6 | Menor/Inc   |
|        11 | N/Categoria |
|         1 | Int.Cons.   |
|         2 | Delegado    |
|         3 | Personal    |
|         4 | Comun       |
|         5 | Proveedor   |
|         6 | Menor/Inc   |
|        11 | N/Categoria |
+-----------+-------------+
```

There's no index defined on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the records in a couple of ways.  I would probably recommend using a temporary table and then re-populating the table correctly:

```
create temporary table temp_categories as 
    select c.id, c.descripcion
    from categories c
    group by c.id;

truncate table categories;

insert into categories(id, descripcion)
    select id, descripcion
    from temp_categories;


alter table add constraint primary key (id);
alter table add constraint unq_categories_descripcion unique (descripcion);
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I'd Just like to add that I had to create a temporary table (CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_categories), because of a lack of privileges, but everything worked nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If/since creating a new table is not an option, you can run something like this; but you'll need to run it repeatedly until it all duplicates are gone.

```
DELETE FROM categories 
WHERE (categoria, descripcion) IN (
   SELECT categoria, descripcion 
   FROM categories 
   GROUP BY categoria, descripcion 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
LIMIT 1
;
```

---

Edit: actually, this should have the benefit of the temp table solution without the risk (*since true temp tables are session/connection based, if your connection fails you would lose the data*).

```
INSERT INTO categories (categoria, descripcion)
SELECT DISTINCT categoria, CONCAT('NEWCOPY---', descripcion)
FROM categories
;

DELETE FROM categories
WHERE descripcion NOT LIKE 'NEWCOPY---%'
;

UPDATE categories
SET descripcion = REPLACE(descripcion, 'NEWCOPY---', '')
;
```

Obviously, 'NEWCOPY---' can/should be replaced with a prefix you KNOW is not present in the table.

Comment: I ended up following the temp_table solution, but this could be a good alternative if someone lacks create privileges for temp tables too.

Comment: @Sebastianb see edit for another alternative (safer than temp tables).

Answer (score 0):

In this example you gave you can do this pretty easy:

```
 CREATE TABLE xyz AS SELECT DISTINCT FROM categories;
 DROP TABLE categories;
 ALTER TABLE xyz RENAME categories;
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_nn_c_1 ON categories(id);
```

(Check the SQL before running else you will loose a table at the `DROP` line)

Comment: This could work, but I don't have CREATE TABLE privileges in the db. Could it work with temp tables, somehow?

Comment: You could as alternative dump the data in a flat file, truncate the categories table and reload the data.

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
 delete a from yourtable a1 , yourtable a2 where a1.categoria=a2.categoria
```

Comment: I think MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244

Comment: oops  sorry, I thought its in MSSQL